# currentCenter returning nil iOS while using Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-places-api, core-location

The JSON Data

Please HELP I beg

```
  2015-10-30 12:15:58.866 GooglePlaces[17141:989254] Google Data: (
    {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "55.599881";
                lng = "-2.64616";
            };
        };
        icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png";
        id = 4e3047fc80549f89389827d05fb89a999705fcf2;
        name = "Scott's view";
        photos =         (
                        {
                height = 2368;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113818044483598102211\">Clarke Thomas</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRdAAAADgCHDAr9O_RZg24-kHykYexBOTpKfhOAWTV-K1Go-sn6CGUoikhGc3beyjErYvXzCPLwFLRr32lC8tPpgfIA-CXue6l75ziHrlRXMOt72IZFBcbZfCBSSbttW5lHjSdfEhD5d08GC5Myl8L1_Zs0VmW2GhTzCD7bh_klEqsROxGDZLvskhzaBw";
                width = 3200;
            }
        );
        "place_id" = ChIJP5eCRF54h0gR9nc97bjfO8k;
        rating = "4.7";
        reference = "CmRgAAAAfN6yeOvYQEeRAzOcidZiE83kPoIdw_vDDH7orFr3gbZVXHeb3prAMlOCVWnVqeeK786c8x-V1QUtWfpSn-50Bk4Q5lO7fY04cNLsXigf1nx1JWiTee5d4TdKI1ij-jGDEhDXYtJPM_1H5t9KhqdSJiyuGhQAXqV2rosfllEOfE-suQ_ur89Bmg";
        scope = GOOGLE;
        types =         (
            parking,
            "point_of_interest",
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = B6356;
    },
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "55.756977";
                lng = "-4.17221";
            };
        };
        icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png";
        id = 481f927c8ea30c24ae902a14dd85efd7e2bae1d1;
        name = "Kwik Fit";
        "opening_hours" =         {
            "open_now" = 1;
            "weekday_text" =             (
            );
        };
        photos =         (
                        {
                height = 608;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118136503820442451002\">Kwik Fit</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRdAAAAY152xIVsahSMoZgsMMN1IdIlMq6fbPeMCJ_1feXg1BIOhRTaW-s_wauDF8WSVPXnOG4dOR3nE9fLzqHmTmdoyKIAef_tZVFKOK43880DeItFOKNejmt_QaEamB4nX8uvEhCPQYbVi8day5vi1KSzGPFtGhT8KzkGs_FuA5ZM11lydRplhPM8uA";
                width = 1080;
            }
        );
        "place_id" = "ChIJ1zdwq2s_iEgR1fI1QvrsCas";
        reference = "CmRcAAAAkkARPnw1ApSjDPECBxsmTmcDDr5LESbSAWF0aNPvI2rX8BDJGfUj3dytKOotK2IbsCUaFbbhYZ8mgoDXfvYqtGliy2v06F2CarEAPSfD_25BGRYqUBsNKYiO05c-seGUEhDsuTEEt6PPKoZhmkBkj2VFGhQ-5vq-S7o73KmF2zw-MIJsPpWYgg";
        scope = GOOGLE;
        types =         (
            store,
            parking,
            "car_repair",
            "point_of_interest",
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "1 Telford Road, East Kilbride";
    },
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "55.618894";
                lng = "-2.810683";
            };
        };
        icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png";
        id = 8ec3c7e9dc0da1d102d516107178cd440579ecff;
        name = "Kwik-Fit";
        "opening_hours" =         {
            "open_now" = 1;
            "weekday_text" =             (
            );
        };
        photos =         (
                        {
                height = 608;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102672183870059691928\">Kwik-Fit</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRdAAAAfbp51L51v3Mz4STPTBbUPvSy8b0GW_PYHQMcP6kXBDKIqhANAnVJINu3mdJk4mrEnG8-RSmR9SBa59z9qjRSxIVSEJapVWMSgGZzLHC3EVnib3-P3n1PnJyewKHVzR2tEhC5qWkLkJlXZl-6ETTap3GZGhSZCS6Wm9jEVAHx0nHwMTi6TNkVsw";
                width = 1080;
            }
        );
        "place_id" = ChIJqf1X7LyEh0gRK7GrZbR1qlI;
        reference = "CmRbAAAAoIW6Uer6wFdg9f9c_kRg0s5Wc-6wyUwg49CWQtn9hphJTfCqmidaP_unuejhxZBS_hChwfTHYWsspU7nOOFZx08cmzQ9bAW7cTp1N7vxepNfqR1YNybBBtB4romQAZO7EhCfxI62ia7XGtVPIyEPRSIPGhR4HnxB4lrDp1o4daDSipUAvFoG4Q";
        scope = GOOGLE;
        types =         (
            store,
            parking,
            "car_repair",
            "point_of_interest",
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "Bridge Street, Galashiels";
    },
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "55.827528";
                lng = "-4.041783";
            };
        };
        icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png";
        id = 993dd6caf6e87b27c95b597170f82fc535db8464;
        name = "Scania Truck Rental";
        photos =         (
                        {
                height = 416;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111565851399356378888\">Ian McCully</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRdAAAAgxB25gl4CRnm6PENE9QPRq0WqPqIFUQCrvz7eOWsirTLMLZM_3gd_plKy9teW9AQdDIIZ3Ikmz96ADPiPD-wtDRvjDFMZl274q1HuA4zg8gVNi6QggypXkSPDdOdrfxUEhCf_qaIvJK0_iWgvnmT-TjcGhSRvsf9XiE5hkqcgwQdbKTm7oI5FA";
                width = 640;
            }
        );
        "place_id" = "ChIJ0YTxdlVqiEgRlNZz-R6gs9M";
        reference = "CnRnAAAAGNBVd-2Rzx_pF8lzxZ5WsI1qC8752BhlsKAXwS36PkmNVCZ4VQkH2FjmRDJ3swxoGLfJ0YmG4Cr1MACDFNaPSv0QdBo5zjIXQyRfytk77g2g0XVspPR7IhO9mQpuQHNCA-DDp5m1ph_ry1W3kt8IahIQiW-loOYmR9yACbxLie-eyhoUQF04W9ZNAeasiM5OqTqPlyDn6g8";
        scope = GOOGLE;
        types =         (
            parking,
            "car_repair",
            "point_of_interest",
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "Melford Road, Bellshill";
    },
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "55.778158";
                lng = "-4.053103";
            };
        };
        icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png";
        id = 5b4e2e7beef36bc21e795144d512adb9cbc9ba54;
        name = "National Tyres and Autocare";
        "opening_hours" =         {
            "open_now" = 1;
            "weekday_text" =             (
            );
        };
        photos =         (
                        {
                height = 631;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100159584019554234022\">National Tyres and Autocare</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRdAAAALn7YnxOv_yKF3Sfkau09mJ1T7aY_L7La0E_2dxN9AGndS6evIYUPWCvYrQgSxD6Y69IsdGhkh08iY4gX0-YgXrbdtD0OBW6y8AjwVjYA34FLAAH9c122Kr_ImAGAmogREhDUOxeBxKmpZPcawyxxfnC9GhTJNNzPhS1xvgh_XPBXGOdhFhFgpQ";
                width = 789;
            }
        );
        "place_id" = ChIJrVjMcTMViEgRqc4gOlJfoDs;
        reference = "CnRuAAAAoOOZVebI5pz8rifXu3_n9RbZv0sobjodbPcP1DhknZcwTuZ_zCjch7l3D0tPqSO21S4wQlhYuH6tOrgBzHwkYBcRMS2-XP5r234IevwkdYV04gAk4BPBfuJMQIyrvASsDtRN9LJkPp8By7OleSyyqhIQco-kf732PwomY9loLvEtbBoUc2ZZKVbvMIYk0pVeFQronor3UM8";
        scope = GOOGLE;
        types =         (
            store,
            parking,
            "car_repair",
            "point_of_interest",
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "Peacock Cross, Almada Street, Hamilton";
    }

2015-10-30 12:16:05.573 GooglePlaces[17141:989254]  name Yosemite National Park
```

The header file
Where currentCenter is defined

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
    #define kGOOGLE_API_KEY @"the key here"

    @interface AboutPlaceViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate>
    {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager;
        CLLocation *location;
// Where Current Centre is defined
        CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre;
        int currenDist;
        BOOL firstLaunch;

    }

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *placeLabell;

    @end
```

The Implementation file

```
#import "AboutPlaceViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AboutPlaceViewController ()

@end

@implementation AboutPlaceViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
     location = [locationManager location];
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSDictionary *jsonDic = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    [self getApiResponse:&jsonDic];
    NSLog(@"jsonDic %@",jsonDic);
    NSDictionary *resultDic = [jsonDic[@"results"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *name = resultDic[@"name"];
    NSLog(@" name %@", name);
    self.placeLabell.text = name;
 }
-(void)getApiResponse:(NSDictionary**)dataDictionary
 {
    // Where i dig into the Json array one example provided above
    NSDictionary *responseDict  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    responseDict = [responseDict valueForKey:@"geometry"];
     NSArray *responseArray = [responseDict valueForKey:@"location"];
    NSDictionary *dict;
    // The for loop it doesnt go inside the for loop when debugging
    for(int i = 0; i< [responseDict count]; i++){
        dict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"- %@",[responseArray objectAtIndex:i]);
     }
    // Where I declare but it returns nil :(
    currentCentre.latitude = [dict[@"lat"]doubleValue];
    currentCentre.longitude = [dict[@"lng"]doubleValue];

    NSString *api_key = kGOOGLE_API_KEY;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",currentCentre.latitude   , currentCentre.longitude,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist],api_key];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
                    request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonObject copyItems:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The responseDict and the responseArray are also returning nil.

The currentCenter is returning nil and when I debug the code it doesn't go into the for loop.  I have looked into the json format to find.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question and repost it? All the help I tried to give you is gone.

Comment: In the future, just update your current question. You don't need a new question to update it.

Comment: I think the line `NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseDict  valueForKey:@"geometry"];`  has a problem. Theres is nothing in `responseDict`. I guess you have to get data from `dataDictionary`.

Comment: It doesn't work i can't pass dataDictionary when i declare the responseDict method

Comment: Anamica show me your full response which you posted in top first.Then only we can give exact result or answer.

Comment: let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Anamica,  from ViewDidLoad you are calling

NSDictionary *jsonDic = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
[self getApiResponse:&jsonDic];

And in "getApiResponse" you wrote

 NSDictionary *responseDict  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
 responseDict = [responseDict valueForKey:@"geometry"]; 

responseDict allocated in memory without any key-value & you are fetching value for Key "geometry".

Similar case is for responseArray.

Answer (score 0):

First on all: 
You have the following line:

```
 location = [locationManager location];

 You call the location straight after you initialise the manager.
 If you look at the location method description it says:

/*
 *  location
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *      The last location received. Will be nil until a location has been received.
 */
 @property(readonly, nonatomic, copy, nullable) CLLocation *location;
```

I.E you should wait till the first location has been received.
Your class needs to implement CLLocationManagerDelegate and override:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
```

Make sure that you requestAlwaysAuthorization before you access the user location

Moreover,
What are you trying to do in this line?

```
 NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseDict  valueForKey:@"geometry"];
```

You are basically defining the dictionary and use it straight away.

Comment: i am trying to dig inside the JSON Array to find the location parameter JSON File is shown above.

Comment: That is because the location parameter is inside the geometry parameter

Comment: You have to change the name of the dictionary or do:
responseDict = [responseDict  valueForKey:@"geometry"];

your line is like doing:   int i = i + 5;
i is uninitialised when used within it's own initialising

Comment: I have updates my question but it still doesn't go inside the for loop when debugging and responseDict and responseArray are returning nil

Comment: NSDictionary *responseDict  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    responseDict = [responseDict valueForKey:@"geometry"];
ResponseDict is a new dictionary at that point!

Comment: But when i do responseDict = responseDict = [responseDict valueForKey:@"geometry"]; it returns an build error stating Use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: I don't understand what  you're trying to do:
you're taking the empty   NSDictionary *jsonDic = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    [self getApiResponse:&jsonDic]; and try to get data from where?
You have to pass another dictionary to parse!
 You don't have any dictionary that you're parsing from in the  getApiResponse method

Comment: I am Using the jsonDic to retrieve the name parameter in the JSON Data  as when i write jsonDic[@"results"]; i get inside the results and then when i type jsonDic[@"name"]; i try to to get the name parameter in the Json data after that i make it to be the value of the placeable but now in the getApi Response method the location is returning nil and i need a way so the location does not return nill and can go inside the JSON Data and find the name parameter and according to the lat and long you've got make the placeLabell that

Comment: For example for lat = "40.758178";
                lng = "-73.983547"; the name parameter is name = "Broadway @ Times Square Hotel";  so i want the placeLabell =  "Broadway @ Times Square Hotel";

Answer (score 0):

Anamica first of all you need to get the latitude and longitude value correctly.If you don not get that,you can't get other details by passing latitude and longitude values.

Getting Latitude and longitude values from your response

```
NSString *lataddr=[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *longaddr=[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

Then pass these strings to your url.Now you can get the response without nil.

Also please remove below coding from your part

```
NSArray *responseArray = [responseDict valueForKey:@"location"];
NSDictionary *dict;
// The for loop it doesnt go inside the for loop when debugging
for(int i = 0; i< [responseDict count]; i++){
    dict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"- %@",[responseArray objectAtIndex:i]);
 }
// Where I declare but it returns nil :(
currentCentre.latitude = [dict[@"lat"]doubleValue];
currentCentre.longitude = [dict[@"lng"]doubleValue];
```

instead of these part, you need to add

```
NSString *lataddr=[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *longaddr=[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lng"];

currentCentre.latitude = [lataddr doubleValue];
currentCentre.longitude = [longaddr doubleValue];
```

Above code for getting only single latitude and longitude value.

Now if you want  to get the multiple latitude and longitude values for showing in map

```
NSMutableArray *arrayLat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrayLng = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; //This is for actually you are getting response to dict.
NSArray *arrayResponse = [dict copy];
NSLog(@"The response is - %@",arrayResponse);
for(int i=0;i<[arrayResponse count];i++)
{
   NSString *lataddr=[[[[[arrayResponse objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"]valueForKey:@"lat"];
   NSString *longaddr=[[[[[arrayResponse objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"]valueForKey:@"lng"];

   [arrayLat addObject:lataddr];
   [arrayLng addObject:longaddr];
}
for(int j=0;j<[arrayLat count];j++)
{
  currentCentre.latitude = [[arrayLat objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue];
  currentCentre.longitude = [[arrayLng objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue];
  NSString *api_key = kGOOGLE_API_KEY;
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",currentCentre.latitude   , currentCentre.longitude,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist],api_key];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSURLResponse *response;
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
                request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

  NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

  dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonObject copyItems:YES];

}
```

All the best Anamica:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *responseDict  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
responseDict = [responseDict valueForKey:@"geometry"];
```

These two lines of code are utter nonsense. Throw away any thought of what you think what these do lines *should do*, but look at them and figure out what they are doing. How code responseDict possibly be anything other than nil after executing these two lines?

Answer (score 0):

As I found(If I am right) you are trying to fetch values from son  data form server.

You can use NSJsonSerilazation for getting data from NSData. Below is only a demo code for getting values

```
  NSData *yourDataFromServer;
    NSError*error;
    id records=  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:yourDataFromServer options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    if (error!=nil)
    {
        if ([records isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])  //Since you are getting Array Of Dictionary
        {
            NSDictionary *dictAtZeroIndex = records[0];
            NSDictionary *latLonDict= [dictAtZeroIndex valueForKey:@"geometry"];  //Again it will be a dictionary. For safety, Here you can again check wheter you are getting dictionary or array using "isKindOfClass"

        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"error is :%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

"yourDataFromServer" is NSData object coming from server. Might be helpful. Let me know if you are having any query. Use valueForKey with "latLonDict" for getting lat-lon values.